# please compare QTP, RIATest , Selenium for Flex Application Automation Testing

Tags: apache-flex, testing, selenium, qtp

Please suggest which tool should I use - QTP, RIATest, Selenium for Flex Application Functional Automation Testing. Please help me compare them with different advantages and disadvantages.
Any help appreciated.

Comment: Have you considered adding FlexMonkey in your list?
I haven't tried the other tools so I can't compare. However, seeing that Selenium is free, I will probably check it out soon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The big picture is:

[QTP](http://www8.hp.com/us/en/software/enterprise-software.html) - sophisticated, expensive, can automate almost anything, not just Flex applications, works on Windows.

[RIATest](http://www.riatest.com/) - simple, inexpensive, designed specifically and only for Flex application, works on Windows and Mac.

Sorry, no experience with Selenium.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have direct experience with it, but there is a [Selenium Flex API](http://code.google.com/p/sfapi/) available; since Selenium is free and open source, it's a great option if your budget is tight.

I do have experience with Selenium in general and can highly recommend it; it's relatively easy to learn and works on any platform with a multiplicity of browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Recently I evaluated the above tools for our Orgnisation.
I say go with QTP. The configuring of qtp for flex is easy.
I wrote a hub about it.
http://hubpages.com/hub/Automating-Flex-Applications-with-QTP
Please ask questions if you have any.
Follow me n my hub

Answer (score 0):

QTP does work with Flex apps...just have to have the right versions.

Answer (score 0):

I was using Selenium to test Flex for a while, then Sun came out with a new plugin for Java in the browser with 1.6.14 I think it was, and I wasn't able to get it to work after that, though I admit its been quite a while since I tried.